# Codesandbox and importing Github repos built with Vue-CLI: TypeError Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: github, vue-cli-3, codesandbox

I have an app built using Vue-Cli and it works fine locally, however, when I import the code from Github into Codesandbox, I get the following error:

[image]

And I get squigly red line/error here:

[image]

Anyone know what I need to do to fix?

**You can access the sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-greider-ri1w7?file=/src/components/PhotoDetail.vue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the empty `<style>` tags in your components, seems like it doesn't play nicely with Codesandbox.

Reference:
https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1912#issuecomment-492518145